# Put a table above a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I would like to create a small table to use above a node in tikz. It consists of a number, centered, followed by an arrow, then three pairs of numbers, with an arrow and a line between them. This is what I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{4}   \\
%Arrow
\multicolumn{2}{c}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[<-] (-.5,0) -- (.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
}                       \\
1   &   2               \\
%Arrow    
\multicolumn{2}{c}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-.5,0) -- (.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
}                       \\
10  &   20              \\
%Line    
\multicolumn{2}{c}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-.5,0) -- (.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
}                       \\
15  &   25              \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I wonder if there's a better approach to do this (like decreasing the vertical space between a pair of numbers and arrow). Also, how can I put this above a node?

Comment: Would you also be interested in a solution in which the whole thing is drawn in tikz?

Comment: @marmot Yes, I would. Actually, at first I tried `\matrix[matrix of nodes]` to create the table, but I couldn't find a way to put the arrows and line.

Comment: With a tabular or even a matrix, every row has a minimum size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proposal that allows you to keep the tabular and just adds the arrows as overlays.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner
     sep=0pt]{\node(#1)[inner sep=0pt]{#2};}}


\begin{tabular}{cc}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{4}   \\[2mm]
\tikznode{1}{1}   &   \tikznode{2}{2}               \\[1mm]
\tikznode{10}{10}  &   \tikznode{20}{20}              \\[1mm]
\tikznode{15}{15}  &   \tikznode{25}{25}              \\
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[latex-] ([yshift=1mm]1.north west) -- ([yshift=1mm]2.north east);
\draw[-latex] ([yshift=1mm]10.north west) -- ([yshift=1mm]20.north east);
\draw[-] ([yshift=1mm]15.north west) -- ([yshift=1mm]25.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you think that's too jammed up just increase the distance(s) `1mm`.

As for your comment, here is a way to make a row of the table a node.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner
     sep=0pt]{\node(#1)[inner sep=0pt]{#2};}}


\begin{tabular}{cc}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{4}   \\[2mm]
\tikznode{1}{1}   &   \tikznode{2}{2}               \\[1mm]
\tikznode{10}{10}  &   \tikznode{20}{20}              \\[1mm]
\tikznode{15}{15}  &   \tikznode{25}{25}              \\[1mm]
\tikznode{175}{17.5}  &   \tikznode{275}{27.5}              \\
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[latex-] ([yshift=1mm]1.north west) -- ([yshift=1mm]2.north east);
\draw[-latex] ([yshift=1mm]10.north west) -- ([yshift=1mm]20.north east);
\draw[-] ([yshift=1mm]15.north west) -- ([yshift=1mm]25.north east);
\node[draw,fit=(175) (275)]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that’s exactly what I was looking for. If I create a rectangle node, how can I put this above it?

Comment: I wanted to put the node just below the table